# Array filter algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I have two `String` arrays as shown below. I want to create a 3rd `String` array `st3` as shown.

```
String[] st1 = {"apple1", "apple2", "apple3","apple4", "apple5","apple6","apple7", "apple8"};

String[] st2 = {"orange1", "orange2", "orange3","orange4", "orange5", "orange6","orange7", "orange8"};

// st3 = [apple1,apple2,  orange1,orange2,
// apple3,apple4,  orange3,orange4,
// apple5,apple6,  orange5,orange6,
// apple7,apple8,  orange7,orange8]

String[] st3 = new String[st1.length *2];
int j = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < st1.length; i++) {
    String a = st1[i];
    String b = st1[i];

    st3[j] = a;
    j++;
    st3[j] = b;
    j++;


    // System.out.println(st3);
}
```

Any help in an algorithm?

Comment: Whats your question? See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It'd be a lot better if you could tell us what isn't working right/what should be different here. What output are you getting? As your question stands, it's not very clear what you're trying to ask IMO.

Comment: Please tag only the programming language you actually use. This doesn't look like c#

Comment: @shmosel Sorry, that has multiple flaws.

Comment: Apart from String b = st1[i]; which should be String b = st2[i]; I found no issue with the algorithm already given ... am I missing something?

Comment: @shmosel 1) The method `range(int, int)` in the type `IntStream` is not applicable for the arguments `(int)` --- 2) Result is incorrect: `[apple1, apple2, orange1, orange2, apple2, apple3, orange2, orange3, apple3, apple4, orange3, orange4, apple4, apple5, orange4, orange5]`

Comment: @mettleap Code alternates singles `[apple1, orange1, apple2, orange2, apple3, ...]`, but OP wants alternating pairs `[apple1, apple2, orange1, orange2, apple3, ...]`

Comment: @Andreas, Ok got it :) ... it's written in the comments which I missed

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of bit-manipulation, you can do it like this:

```
String[] st3 = new String[st1.length * 2];
for (int i = 0; i < st3.length; i++) {
    int j = i >> 1 & ~1 | i & 1;
    st3[i] = (i & 2) == 0 ? st1[j] : st2[j];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(st3));
```

*Output*

```
[apple1, apple2, orange1, orange2, apple3, apple4, orange3, orange4, apple5, apple6, orange5, orange6, apple7, apple8, orange7, orange8]
```

*Explanation:*

The bits of `i` are `aaaaaabc`, where bit one (`b`) specifies which array to take value from and `aaaaaac` specifies the index into that array.

To check if bit one is 0: `(i & 2) == 0`

To remove bit one, you shift value right (`i >> 1` = `aaaaaab`), remove the `b` value (`& ~1` = `aaaaaa0`), get the `c` value (`i & 1` = `c`), and combine them (`|`).

Operator precedence is such that no parentheses are needed.
To be explicit, it would be `((i >> 1) & ~1) | (i & 1)`

Comment: As this question seems like a school assignment, I would like to see the OP presenting your answer as the solution!!!

Comment: @forpas Hey, OP was asking for algorithm, and this is a great one *(in my opinion)*. Whether it's using constructs beyond what OP is supposed to know about, is a separate issue, and no constraints were listed in the question.

Comment: Of course this is an answer to the question. I'm just saying that it is not what the OP would hope for.